# Class Zend\Console\Response does not exist After Magento 2 upgrade

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, composer, setup-di-compile, composer.json

After upgrade from Magento 2.4.2 to 2.4.4, and run

```
bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

I got this error

```
Class Zend\Console\Response does not exist
```

This is my composer.json file

```
{
"name": "magento/project-community-edition",
"description": "eCommerce Platform for Growth (Community Edition)",
"type": "project",
"version": "2.2.1",
"license": [
    "OSL-3.0",
    "AFL-3.0"
],
"require": {
    "magento/product-community-edition": "2.4.4",
    "magento/composer-dependency-version-audit-plugin": "~0.1",
    "composer/composer": "@alpha",
    "cart2quote/module-autoproposal": "^1.0",
    "magento/zendframework1": "1.15.0",
    "mageplaza/magento-2-french-language-pack": "dev-master",
    "imaginaerum/magento2-language-fr-fr": "*",
    "mageplaza/module-google-recaptcha": "^1.0",
    "fooman/emailattachments-m2": "^3.0",
    "fooman/printorderpdf-m2": "^3.1",
    "symfony/yaml": "dev-issue-8145",
    "fooman/sameorderinvoicenumber-m2": "^3.0",
    "kiwicommerce/module-admin-activity": "^1.0",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.3.0",
    "ebizmarts/mailchimp-lib": "^3.0",
    "magento/composer-root-update-plugin": "~2.0",
    "symfony/console": "4.4.26"
},
"require-dev": {
    "phpunit/phpunit": "~6.2.0",
    "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "3.2.2",
    "phpmd/phpmd": "@stable",
    "pdepend/pdepend": "2.5.2",
    "friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer": "2.19.0",
    "lusitanian/oauth": "~0.8.10",
    "sebastian/phpcpd": "~3.0.0",
    "symfony/finder": "^5.2"
},
"replace": {
    "dotmailer/dotmailer-magento2-extension": "*",
    "dotmailer/dotmailer-magento2-extension-package": "*",
    "dotmailer/dotmailer-magento2-extension-enterprise": "*",
    "dotmailer/dotmailer-magento2-extension-chat": "*",
    "amzn/amazon-pay-and-login-magento-2-module": "*",
    "klarna/module-core": "*",
    "klarna/module-kp": "*",
    "klarna/module-ordermanagement": "*",
    "shopialfb/facebook-module": "*",
    "magento/module-signifyd": "*"
},
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Magento\\Framework\\": "lib/internal/Magento/Framework/",
        "Magento\\Setup\\": "setup/src/Magento/Setup/",
        "Magento\\": "app/code/Magento/"
    },
    "psr-0": {
        "": [
            "app/code/"
        ]
    },
    "files": [
        "app/etc/NonComposerComponentRegistration.php"
    ],
    "exclude-from-classmap": [
        "**/dev/**",
        "**/update/**",
        "**/Test/**"
    ]
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Magento\\Sniffs\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/Sniffs/",
        "Magento\\Tools\\": "dev/tools/Magento/Tools/",
        "Magento\\Tools\\Sanity\\": "dev/build/publication/sanity/Magento/Tools/Sanity/",
        "Magento\\TestFramework\\Inspection\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Inspection/",
        "Magento\\TestFramework\\Utility\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Utility/"
    }
},
"minimum-stability": "stable",
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "composer",
        "url": "https://repo.magento.com/"
    }
],
"extra": {
    "magento-force": "override"
},
"config": {
    "allow-plugins": {
        "magento/magento-composer-installer": true,
        "magento/inventory-composer-installer": true,
        "laminas/laminas-dependency-plugin": true,
        "magento/composer-root-update-plugin": true,
        "magento/composer-dependency-version-audit-plugin": true
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Zend components are being gradually removed and replaced by Laminas equivalents.

Comment: Do you know which Laminas package should i add?

Comment: I'm afraid that I don't. However, in most cases the Laminas packages are already added. Magento is simply transferring functionality from Zend to Laminas. You may be able find a package that provides the same functionality by searching for one with similar class methods, etc.